# Uploading an innherHtml delivered element to a database using a form in Laravel 4

Tags: javascript, mysql, forms, laravel-4, innerhtml

In javascript, I have an innerHtml element that I am trying to upload to my mysql database using a form in Laravel 4.

In the javascript, I have:

```
document.getElementById("myUrl").innerHTML = FPFile.url;
```

This is the url I would like to upload to my database.

Then, in the view, I have:

```
{{Form::hidden('myUrl',null, array(
    'id'     => 'myUrl',
));}}
```

This is my attempt to upload the url to the database as part of a form.

In my controller, I have:

```
 $artist->image_path = Input::get('myUrl');
```

The column is called image_path, and the object in the view is 'myUrl'.

When I click submit for the form, url is not uploaded.

Do you see anything I have done wrong?  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("myURL").value = FPFile.url;
```